# Why i am getting $\sqrt{i^4} = \sqrt{1/2} + i\sqrt{1/2}$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I used the method to find the square root of complex numbers and it did work for $0 + i \times i^3$.

$$x + iy = \sqrt{i^4}$$
$$x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi = i^4$$

equating the components,
$$x^2 - y^2 = 0$$
$$2xy = 1$$

using,
$$(x^2 + y^2)^2 = (x^2 - y^2)^2 + (2xy)^2$$

$$(x^2 + y^2)^2 = 1$$
$$x^2 + y^2 = 1$$

$$x^2 = {1\over 2}$$
$$x = \pm\sqrt{1\over 2}$$

$$y = \pm\sqrt{1\over 2}$$

$$\therefore \pm\sqrt{1\over 2} + \pm i\sqrt{1\over 2} = i^4$$

But $i^4$ is 1 so the $\sqrt{i^4} = \pm1$.

It would be nice if someone could point out my mistake.

Comment: Since $i^4=1$, the real part is $1$ and the imaginary part is $0$; so equating the components gives $x^2-y^2=1$ and $2xy=0$. Your equations $x^2-y^2=0$ and $2xy=-1$ refer to the square roots of $-i$.

Comment: @egreg So i should have imaginary part in simplest form to get right results otherwise this algorithm does not work, right ?

Comment: Equating the components gives you $x^2 -y^2=1$ not 0.  And $2xy= 0$ not 1.  You just solved for $\sqrt {i}$ and you did it correctly.  But $i \ne i^4$.  $i = 0 + 1i $  but $i^4=1+0i $.

Comment: The algorithm works fine! But when you get $(x^2 -y^2) + 2xyi = a + bi $ you have to set $(x^2 -y^2) $ or a; not b.  And you have to set 2xyi to b; not a.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks, got it.

Comment: $i^4$ is not "the imaginary part".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $x^2 - y^2 + 2xyi = i^4$, remember that $i^4=1$, so $$x^2-y^2=1,\quad 2xy=0$$

Comment: does it mean that i should have complex number in simplest form to perform this algorithm ?

Comment: You don't _have_ to, but it makes it easier to see what the real part and imaginary part.

Answer (score 1):

You wish to solve $(re^{i\theta})^2 = r^2e^{i2\theta} = i^4 =1$. Taking the modulus gives $r=1$,
and the solutions to $e^{i2\theta} =1$ are given by 
$2\theta = n 2 \pi$, from which we get the solutions $\pm 1$.